# np.uint16 isn't the same as np.uint16

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to map numpy dtypes to associated values using a dictionary lookup. I observe the following counterintuitive behavior:

```
dtype = np.uint16
x = np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=dtype)
assert x.dtype == dtype
d = {np.uint8: 8, np.uint16: 16, np.uint32: 32, np.float32: 32}
print(dtype in d)  # prints True
print(x.dtype in d)  # prints False
```

Using other dtypes produces similar results.

So we have that `np.uint16 == x.dtype`, but the former is found in the dictionary's keys while the latter is not. Any explanation and/or simple workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dtypes don't work like they look at first glance. `np.uint16` **isn't** a dtype object. It's just convertible to one. `np.uint16` is a type object representing the type of [array scalars](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html) of uint16 dtype.

`x.dtype` is an actual [dtype object](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), and dtype objects implement `==` in a weird way that's non-transitive and inconsistent with `hash`. `dtype == other` is basically implemented as `dtype == np.dtype(other)` when `other` isn't already a dtype. You can see the details in the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#L3166).

Particularly, `x.dtype` compares equal to `np.uint16`, but it doesn't have the same hash, so the dict lookup doesn't find it.

Comment: Do you know why this behavior exists? From the Python docs on [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__): *"The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value;"*. So Numpy decided to infringe this requirement, but why?

Comment: @a_guest: I don't know, but it's too late to change the behavior now.

Answer (score 2):

`x.dtype` returns a `dtype` object (see [dtype class](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html))

To get the type inside, you need to call `x.dtype.type` :

```
print(x.dtype.type in d) # True
```

Comment: Note that dtypes cannot be uniquely identified by their `.type`. For example, all structured dtypes have `dtype.type is numpy.void`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior:

`np.uint16` is non-initialized and therefore `dtype` is actually a class, whereas `x.dtype` is actually a data type object ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html)).

Another answer shows a workaround here.